# DNS , MX and SMTP. Mail storage

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, mx-record, imap

I have basic understanding of how everything works. But I want to get better understanding and dive deeper.

I will how do I understand all these stuff. 
Consider we are sending letter to `hello@world.com`

1. When we are sending letter firstly DNS resolves `world.com` domain.
2. It asks `.` DNS server than it is redirected to `.com.` DNS zone server and than to the `NS` server/servers that are responsible for storing info about `world.com` domain. We can change(redirect to another) `NS` servers in domain control panel.
3. After finding proper `NS` server which is responsible for providing information about this domain it retrieves data about `MX` record.
4. Mail is sent to the SMTP server specified in `MX` record using `SMTP` protocol
5. Because we are not using `POP3` protocol over letter is saved on the `SMTP` server responsible for maintenance of our domain (MX record).
6. So `SMTP` server backups all our mail on the server and we can access our mail from anywhere using `IMAP` protocol.

Am I right ? 
Most of time `MX` record has hoster mail servers specified.

So my main question is

If I change `MX` record of my domain to another server, than I will lost all mail history ? Or it is possible to transfer mail to new server ? And if I switch back again to old `SMTP` server will I find all my mail there or it will be removed ?

Maybe I am completely wrong, but I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5. MX (SMTP-server aka `MTA`) can be configured as destination or relay for some mail domain(s).
6. If it is configured as relay, message will be sent to another MTA that can be destination or relay too. And so forth. MX here is just an entrance point. Message can be routed to the different destinations, duplicated, terminated etc. That is how complex mail infrastructures look inside. Step by step message will be routed to the host, configured as destination. Otherwise, after some number of steps, message will be rejected as non-deliverable.
7. If host is configured as destination, messages are stored locally. That process is performed by `Local Delivery Agent` - LDA. All SMTP servers have some LDA functionality, so they can store messages at least in the `mailbox` format. `Mailbox` is just a plain file with messages appended one by one. Alternatively messages can be stored in the `maildir` or even in the databases like `mysql` or `postgres`.
8. From the local storage messages can be fetched by `Mail User Agent` or MUA like `mutt` or `mail` utilities. But if your messages are stored on the remote host, you need some service like `POP3` or `IMAP` to fetch messages over network.

So messages are stored on the host not because there is no POP3 on the MX. That is happens because MX is configured as destination for domain and LDA is configured properly. Otherwise message will be returned to the sender with notification: can't deliver.

> If I change MX record of my domain to another server, than I will lost
>   all mail history ? Or it is possible to transfer mail to new server ?

The common approach is to configure your MX as relay that will route all the mail to the server, configured as destination. You can change MXses as you wish as long as they relay to the same destination server. But you also can physically move your mail storage to the other server as far as it's just plain files.

Popular email software like `sendmail`, `postfix`, `exim`, `qmail`, `dovecot` etc are powerful enough to build any configuration you want. But that require strong knowledge and skills, as far as you can easily become the victim of spammers who can use poorly configured server as spamgun.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say old mail server is `mail1.world.com`and that new server is `mail2.world.com`. MX record pointing to old server would be

```
world.com in mx 0 mail1.world.com.
```

and mx record pointing to new:

```
world.com in mx 0 mail2.world.com.
```

What happens when you change your mx record is the mail will be delivered to server responding to new mx record - mail2.world.com. New server doesn't have any notion about activities on old server, it has no content (accounts, messages, logs, settings), unless you configure everything first and copy content from old server. 
As for changing setting to old server. Mail server will function same is it's working now and with all content it had previously, unless you have scripts that are clearing old messages. You should be able to access both servers no matter where mx record is pointing, only difference is that mail for your domain will be deliverd to server mx is pointing to.

Hope this clears things a bit.